# Log files fill up too fast

Tags: drivers, nvidia, log, syslog

I have gone through my logs and found these lines repeating:

```
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187604] wlp0s20f3:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x0
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187620] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 4074 at /build/linux-hwe-eg6_iE/linux-hwe-5.3.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 drv_sta_state+0x165/0x400 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187620] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(PO) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) nvidia(PO) joydev hid_multitouch hid_generic iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_realtek mac80211 snd_hda_codec_generic libarc4 ledtrig_audio i915 8250_dw ipmi_devintf idma64 sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ipmi_msghandler snd_hda_codec_hdmi uvcvideo v4l2_common videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect virt_dma sysimgblt snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_rawmidi snd_seq rtsx_pci_ms memstick snd_seq_device snd_timer intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187635]  kvm_intel kvm irqbypass btusb crct10dif_pclmul btrtl crc32_pclmul btbcm btintel ghash_clmulni_intel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf input_leds serio_raw intel_wmi_thunderbolt acer_wmi sparse_keymap iwlwifi snd cfg80211 mei_me intel_lpss_pci mei intel_pch_thermal soundcore intel_lpss wmi_bmof acer_wireless mac_hid acpi_pad ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c sch_fq_codel iptable_filter bpfilter parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc r8169 ahci realtek rtsx_pci i2c_hid libahci hid pinctrl_cannonlake pinctrl_intel wmi video
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187652] CPU: 6 PID: 4074 Comm: kworker/6:2 Tainted: P        W  O      5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187652] Hardware name: Acer Nitro AN515-52/Freed_CFS, BIOS V1.28 08/05/2019
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187661] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187671] RIP: 0010:drv_sta_state+0x165/0x400 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187672] Code: 85 c9 75 e3 e9 56 ff ff ff 49 8b 87 50 04 00 00 49 8d b7 70 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 70 89 e2 c0 48 85 c0 48 0f 45 f0 e8 2b 40 0f c5 <0f> 0b 41 bd fb ff ff ff e9 28 ff ff ff 41 83 fc 02 0f 85 82 00 00
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187673] RSP: 0018:ffffaab002a27868 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187674] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff91fe221f07a0 RCX: 0000000000000006
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187674] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff91fe26397440
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187675] RBP: ffffaab002a278a0 R08: 0000000000afdb2f R09: 0000000000000004
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187676] R10: ffffaab002a277f8 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000004
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187676] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: ffff91fe221f0d60 R15: ffff91fe1e0de8c0
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187677] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff91fe26380000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187678] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187679] CR2: 00003a8e085b8004 CR3: 00000001cc80a001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187679] Call Trace:
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187691]  sta_info_move_state+0x284/0x360 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187702]  __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x36/0x1a0 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187714]  __sta_info_flush+0x139/0x1b0 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187729]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xc4/0x5d0 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187742]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x28b/0x450 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187759]  ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187772]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xaf/0x1c0 [cfg80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187785]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x80 [cfg80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187798]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x12b/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187808]  __cfg80211_leave+0x141/0x1a0 [cfg80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187818]  cfg80211_leave+0x2b/0x40 [cfg80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187828]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x253/0x5e0 [cfg80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187843]  ? ieee80211_reconfig+0x248/0x15c0 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187845]  ? vprintk_default+0x29/0x50
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187849]  ? vprintk_func+0x47/0xc0
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187852]  ? __update_load_avg_se+0x11c/0x310
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187855]  ? __update_load_avg_se+0x11c/0x310
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187858]  ? inetdev_event+0x46/0x570
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187861]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187864]  ? skb_dequeue+0x59/0x70
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187868]  notifier_call_chain+0x4c/0x70
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187873]  raw_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187876]  call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x2d/0x60
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187880]  __dev_close_many+0x63/0x120
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187883]  dev_close_many+0x8c/0x140
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187885]  ? __schedule+0x2b0/0x670
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187889]  dev_close.part.98+0x4a/0x70
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187893]  dev_close+0x19/0x20
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187902]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x77/0xd0 [cfg80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187915]  ieee80211_handle_reconfig_failure+0x98/0xb0 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187926]  ieee80211_reconfig+0x252/0x15c0 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187928]  ? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x53/0x80
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187937]  ieee80211_restart_work+0xc0/0xf0 [mac80211]
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187940]  process_one_work+0x1fd/0x3f0
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187942]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187943]  kthread+0x121/0x140
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187945]  ? process_one_work+0x3f0/0x3f0
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187946]  ? kthread_park+0xb0/0xb0
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187948]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187949] ---[ end trace d236872170d913ed ]---
Jul 21 20:16:58 hardik kernel: [ 1532.187957] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

Can anybody tell me how should i resolve these?
Are there any problems with NVIDIA drivers or something else?
Laptop: Acer Nitro 5
Ubuntu: 18.04
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050Ti
NVIDIA-DRIVERS-VERSION: 440
KERNEL: 5.3.0-62-generic

Comment: seemd to me it is a problem with wlan. `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A3`

Comment: Do you think it is a problem with my WiFi card or WiFi driver?

Comment: I've seen this exact error popping up quite a bit lately. I don't know exactly what's wrong, yet. I suspect that it's either 1) an updated kernel problem (try and boot to an older kernel and see if the problem is gone), or 2) a bad `linux-firmware` update, or 3) a bad driver update. I don't suspect hardware. Do you use wireless or ethernet to connect to the Internet?

Comment: I use WiFi. I have tried updating drivers.

Comment: Try booting to an older kernel. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema I think the problem is solved by updating the drivers. Haven't faced this issue after that. Thanks!

Comment: What drivers did you update? How did you update them?

Comment: @heynnema it didn't work. So what I did was that I updated my kernel to v5.3.13 which supports my wifi card. Now i don't see any issues. Thanks!